# Return of the singular tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tagging

Just spotted this poor little thing while doing some tag maintenance in the realm of visa tags:

- [working-visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/working-visa)

Can a kindly mod please attach a pluralizing final "-s" so the other tags stop making fun of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done. [working-visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/working-visa)->[working-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/working-visas). Added the synonym as well.